# Get ARAM match history with League of Legends API

Tags: riot-games-api

Using the League of Legends API, how can I list of all recent games, including ARAM?

This method says it will return match history:
https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/873/3054

But when I test it with my summoner ID (32984235), I get an empty result since I only play ARAM.

I'm assuming it's possible since LoLKing does it - http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/32984235#matches

Comment: This help? http://jsfiddle.net/Zt3u9/71/ It only gets some basic ARAM match data, but maybe it will give you some ideas on how to get your games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, you can fetch your most recent 10 games of any type using the recent game endpoint:

```
 (/api/lol/{region}/v1.3/game/by-summoner/{summonerId}/recent)
```

However, that endpoint is going to be deprecated at some point in favor of the match history endpoints, which include

```
/api/lol/{region}/v2.2/matchlist/by-summoner/{summonerId}
```

and

```
/api/lol/{region}/v2.2/match/{matchId}
```

For now, the match endpoints will only return ranked games. Ultimately though we want to add OAuth support to Riot's public APIs. Once we do that, the idea is that you will be able to fetch all game data for the authenticated user and his friends, which is the same behavior as the in-game match history and the match history website (http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com).